# Docker port error: * Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse

Tags: docker

I have a C# app I'm trying to get running in a docker container

```
.NET 4.5.2 Framework
mono 6.12
Owin rest service
```

The container has the port published

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE        COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS          PORTS                      NAMES
3716895823c5   mytestapp   "mono /opt/mytestapp…"    31 minutes ago   Up 31 minutes   0.0.0.0:23456->23456/tcp   testapp
```

Accessing from inside the container works as expected

```
$ docker exec -it testapp /bin/bash
root@3716895823c5:/# curl -v  http://127.0.0.1:23456/api/v1/sessions/1
* Expire in 0 ms for 6 (transfer 0x562e32e240f0)
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Expire in 200 ms for 4 (transfer 0x562e32e240f0)
* Connected to 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) port 23456 (#0)
> GET /api/v1/sessions/1 HTTP/1.1
> Host: 127.0.0.1:23456
> User-Agent: curl/7.64.0
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
...
<
* Closing connection 0
{"id":1, ....
```

However, when trying from the host I get a `* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse` error.

```
$ curl -v http://127.0.0.1:23456/api/v1/sessions/1
*   Trying 127.0.0.1:23456...
* Connected to 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) port 23456 (#0)
> GET /api/v1/sessions/1 HTTP/1.1
> Host: 127.0.0.1:23456
> User-Agent: curl/7.81.0
> Accept: */*
>
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii
< Server: Mono-HTTPAPI/1.0
< Date: Mon, 26 Sep 2022 20:16:27 GMT
< Content-Length: 35
< Connection: close
<
* Closing connection 0
<h1>Bad Request (Invalid host)</h1>$
```

Since the app works correct when I run it on ubuntu + mono, I assume this is somehow docker related. Unfortunately, I have yet not been able to find any solution for this

Comment: I've rolled back your edit. It is not acceptable here to edit a solution into the question itself. If you've found a solution and want to share it, do so by writing an answer in the space provided below for that purpose. See [Can I answer my own question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) for more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual issue here is not the issue stated in the title, but instead `Bad Request (Invalid host)`

This happens when running app in docker and accessing through exposed port. The issue turns out to be with Owin and how it is set up. With the help from a colleague and this link, we narrowed down the issue and found the solution. [OWIN-WebAPI-Service](https://github.com/danesparza/OWIN-WebAPI-Service#serving-more-than-just-localhost).

Solution is to use `http://+:<port>` for listening for requests.
From the above link

> Second, you'll need to change the code that starts the service.
> Instead of listening for requests to http://localhost:9000, you'll
> need to listen for requests to http://+:9000.

Answer (score 0):

The message "Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse" is not an error, but a benign informational message. It only means that curl is connected with HTTP/1.1 ; the real problem is **HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request**, as @Jesper Kristiansen pointed out above.

Also see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74917358/7859025)

Adding some clarity because the "multiuse" message is a red herring. Hopefully my answer will save someone some time by not chasing this red herring.