# HTTP/1.1 500 Server Error, Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse

Tags: jenkins, nexus

I try to upload tgz file to nexus repo (nexus running in container) through jenkins but it is getting failed with below error.

**Command to upload tgz file.**

'''curl -v -u admin:admin1234 --upload-file artifact.tgz [http://172.00.00.000:8081/repository/tgz/com/my/group/myArtifact/1.0.0/artifact-1.0.0.tgz'''](http://172.00.00.000:8081/repository/tgz/com/my/group/myArtifact/1.0.0/artifact-1.0.0.tgz%27%27%27)

**Error:**

100 4353M    0     0  100 4353M      0  66.9M  0:01:04  0:01:04 --:--:--     0* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse

** HTTP/1.1 500 Server Error**
Server: Nexus/3.42.0-01 (OSS)
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Content-Security-Policy: sandbox allow-forms allow-modals allow-popups allow-presentation allow-scripts allow-top-navigation
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Frame-Options: DENY
Content-Length: 0

i try different solutions like adding **--http1.1** but no use.

Answer (score 0):

That message is not an error (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74917358/7859025)). The 500 server error is the real error, but it's not caused by or related to the "multiuse" message.