# Yaws: How to debug enigmatic HTTP error 500 in a reverse proxy situation?

Tags: http-status-code-500, yaws

## Reverse proxy Yaws delivers 500 Internal Server Error

I use `Yaws` as a reverse proxy. Yaws lives in a docker container named `yaws` which calls an `NGINX` container named `wsm`. Very rarely, I get a **500 Internal Server Error** when called from `Opera` or `Edge` but not from within Yaws.

**How to debug this?**

## Take curl

The same is true when called in Linux with `curl`: we get a **HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error** after due time. Of course,  Yaws is involved here, too.

```
CS-1 16:33:06 :/tmp# curl -v 'https://wp:my_secret@sm.myurl.biz/equivoxx/2181/sitemap/?rrr=1&del=1&ren=1&rss=1&bak=1&x=1&sfp=1&lg=en&del_sm=1'
*   Trying 123.456.240.136:443...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to sm.myurl.biz (123.456.240.136) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
[...]
* SSL connection using TLSv1.3 / TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
* ALPN, server did not agree to a protocol
* Server certificate:
*  subject: CN=myurl.biz
*  start date: Jun 15 00:00:00 2023 GMT
*  expire date: Sep 13 23:59:59 2023 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "sm.myurl.biz" matched cert's "sm.myurl.biz"
*  issuer: C=AT; O=ZeroSSL; CN=ZeroSSL RSA Domain Secure Site CA
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
* Server auth using Basic with user 'wp'
> GET /equivoxx/2181/sitemap/?rrr=1&del=1&ren=1&rss=1&bak=1&x=1&sfp=1&lg=en&del_sm=1 HTTP/1.1
> Host: sm.myurl.biz
> Authorization: Basic d3A6Y2hlZiw0OA==
> User-Agent: curl/7.68.0
> Accept: */*
>
[working]
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
< Connection: close
< Server: Yaws 2.0.9
< Date: Wed, 26 Jul 2023 14:34:28 GMT
< Content-Length: 47
< Content-Type: text/html
< Vary: Accept-Encoding
<
* Closing connection 0
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS alert, close notify (256):
<html><h1>500 Internal Server Error</h1></html>
```

The message `Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse` is not an error message, but a debug trace message of no consequence and does not relate to `HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error` ([Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71171194/curl-mark-bundle-as-not-supporting-multiuse-http-1-1-403/74917358#74917358))

## Runs fine without parameters

E.g., the URL

```
https://sm.myurl.biz/equimyurl/2181/sitemap/
```

runs fine everywhere whereas this URL with a couple of parameters

```
https://sm.myurl.biz/equimyurl/2181/sitemap/?rrr=1&del=1&ren=1&rss=1&bak=1&x=1&sfp=1&lg=en&del_sm=1
```

delivers the error in the browser or curl. Due to the parameters, this URL does some database processing.

Inspecting the parameters, it turns out that only `del_sm` triggers the 500 error. It deletes the old data by dropping some tables which then are recreated and thus renewed. **This is none of Yaws business.** Nothing to worry about, right?

## Taking Yaws out of the picture: Runs fine in NGINX container `wsm`

Running the URL with the same parameters on the NGINX container `wsm` from within the Yaws container `yaws` (so `curl` calls wsm) however is OK:

```
curl -v 'wsm/equivoxx/2181/sitemap?rrr=1&del=1&ren=1&rss=1&bak=1&x=1&sfp=1&lg=en&del_sm=1' | tee /tmp/2181-wsm1.htm
```

The output of curl is as it should be. Calling the output `2181-wsm1.htm` with a browser is flawless. The data is updated fine. Yaws should not alter the output. Nevertheless I get the 500 error.

I have set up a log file `/tmp/tmp_'.$this->id_ex.'__hunt_500.log` recording messages to track the positions in the source code where an error might occur. No surprise. The last entry looks like

```
2023-07-24 19:56:26 elapsed_secs :14: -- L: 1189 M: Imp::_die HUNT_500  this->lg :en: this->id_ex :2181:
```

which tells me that this message was triggered in the module `Imp` at method `_die` which is the last thing the program does before exiting:

```
    function _die() {
        $this->dba->close();
        $this->output->_display();
wp_str_to_file('L: '.__LINE__.' M: '.__METHOD__." this->lg :$this->lg: this->id_ex :$this->id_ex:", 
     '/tmp/tmp_'.$this->id_ex.'__hunt_500.log');
        exit;
    } # _die
```

Hence the program did what it should which, of course, the updated data proved already. Why then has Yaws a problem with the **output** nevertheless?

## Looking at Yaws

I use data caching by `mnesia` with Yaws heavily. Of course, some Urls must not be cached. The parameter `rrr` disables caching, so the output of the offending URL is not touched by Yaws but **passed through** instead.

The relevant appmod functions:

```
out(A) ->
    S = check_intrusion(A#arg.querydata), % out(A) -> 
    if 
        S ->
            out_hello();                            % avoid bad Urls
        true ->                                     
             out_check_log(A)                       % out, real content, filter for cache
    end.

check_intrusion(U) ->                % avoid bad Urls
    case U of
        undefined ->
            0;
        _ ->
            L = ["/solr", "HelloThink", "XDEBUG_SESSION", "phpstorm", "invokefunction", "/TP/public"],
            [string:find(U, N) || N <- L, string:find(U, N) /= nomatch] /= []  
    end.

out_check_log(A) ->                                               
    R = check_log(A),                                          
    if 
        R ->                                           % logging turned on, pass through
            Url = get_uri(A) ++ get_cookies_string(A),         
            pass_through(Url);                              
        true ->                                             
            out_myurl(A)                                % real work, eventually saved by mnesia 
    end.
```

```
check_log(A) ->
    Url = get_uri_string(A),     
    R = string:str(Url, "log=1") > 0,
    R.

out_myurl(A) ->
    Del = yaws_api:queryvar(A, "del"),
    Lg = get_lang(A),                     % Lg is important
    Request_path = get_request_path(A),
    Lg_url = prepend_lg(Lg, Request_path),
    if 
        Del /= undefined ->
                url:delete_record(myurl, Lg),       
                % we have at least lg=...  will delete if we have no GET param
                url:delete_record(myurl, Lg_url);   
                % we have at least lg=...  delete the record
        true ->                                    % out_myurl Del
            ok
    end,
    case skip_this_url(Request_path) of                     
        false ->                          % we want to save or retrieve this
            Start = deb:get_timestamp(),  % timestamp -- a bit late, we miss some cycles
            url:init(),                                            % mnesia
            Html = select_or_record(A, Request_path, Start, Lg),   
            % should replace elapsed time with real data
            Html;     % we get cached data with fresh timestamp
        true ->                                                    
            pass_through(Request_path)    % out_myurl skip_this_url
    end.
```

```
skip_this_url(Url) ->                              % determine URLs not to be cached
    R = string:str(Url, ".ico") > 0
    orelse 
    string:str(Url, "search=") > 0                 % search is so fast and should be fresh
% [...]                                            % lots of conditions
    orelse 
    string:str(Url, "rrr=1") > 0                   % param to not cache
    orelse 
    string:str(Url, ".well-known") > 0             % letsencrypt
    orelse 
    string:str(Url, "uploads/") > 0
    orelse 
    string:str(Url, "xframe/") > 0,
    R.

pass_through(Request_path)  ->           
    Url = check_scheme(Request_path),
    inets:start(),
    ssl:start(),
    Url_2 = string:replace(Url, " ", "%2B"),
    Http_result = httpc:request(Url_2),
    {ok, {{V, S, R}, _, _}} = Http_result,               % we get the results
    case Http_result of
        {ok, {{_Version, 200, _ReasonPhrase}, _Headers, Html}} ->               
                    {html, Html};   % we get the results, display them
        {ok, {{_Version, 401, _ReasonPhrase}, _Headers, Html}} ->             
                    {html, Html};   % auth mechanism
        _ -> 
            {ok, {{_, Status, ReasonPhrase}, _, _}} = Http_result,
            not_200                 % some kind of error
    end.
```

As far as I can see, `rrr=1` invokes `pass_through` which just does a `httpc:request` and passes the result on when we get a `200`.

## Final thoughts

So far, the error affects only the output of the updating mechanism without touching it. This output is rather irrelevant, so I could leave it at that. The data is updated fine, which is the main reason for the job. However, it bugs me, nevertheless.

How can I debug this? I don't use an `interception module` in `yaws.conf` which is noted for 500 errors. Are there any methods to investigate the 500 error?

`wsm` works fine. No idea how this can lead to the error. Why does `yaws` do that?

I stopped yaws in the yaws container with `yaws --stop` and restarted with

```
rm -f /tmp/myurl*.log
yaws -i
```

to turn on debugging. I could not see any difference.

Inspecting `myurl.log`, I find lots of entries of type

```
------2023-07-26 12:57:57---
139
 url:delete_record RECORD NOT FOUND, mnesia:abort(not_exist)
 Key "de"
```

which is just a notification from function `delete_record(Table, Key)` where `Key` cycles through all the 5 languages involved here.

Looking at the trace in yaws I see no difference: both versions end with

```
Mod:myurl line:575 'select_or_record(A)=SELECT_OR_RECORD==SELECT_NOT_FOUND=> INSERT_WEB_PAGE Cookie' ["<!-- : -->"]
```

Any idea where to look for?

Comment: Can you rebuild Yaws with `debug` turned on? It's off by default. That will result in extra debug logging messages that may help pinpoint the source(s) of the 500 status codes. Another alternative is to use Erlang tracing, enabled from the Erlang prompt via `yaws -i`, to determine which Yaws function is sending the 500, but tracing isn't trivial and it would be difficult to explain in this comment how to approach it. Finally, if you could try to create a simpler setup that duplicates the problem, that would also help narrow down the source of the issue.

Comment: I'm afraid I cannot rebuild Yaws. I simply don't know how to do it. But I use tracing a lot. I already noted the last tracing message above. Most probably I haven't put the trace directive at where it counts.  I'll have a look at your last hint. Thank you so far.