# Git clone returning RPC failed; curl 1 Received HTTP/0.9 when not allowed

Tags: git, curl

It happened when I was cloning a repo. It got stucked and throw such an error:

```
POST git-upload-pack (201 bytes)
error: RPC failed; curl 1 Received HTTP/0.9 when not allowed
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

I searched it online and got this:[PHP Curl - Received HTTP/0.9 when not allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59048926/php-curl-received-http-0-9-when-not-allowed) Then I checked my curl version in git and I thought that it supports nghttp2

```
curl 7.75.0 (x86_64-w64-mingw32) libcurl/7.75.0 OpenSSL/1.1.1k (Schannel) zlib/1.2.11 brotli/1.0.9 zstd/1.4.8 libidn2/2.3.0 libssh2/1.9.0 nghttp2/1.41.0
Release-Date: 2021-02-03
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher gophers http https imap imaps ldap ldaps mqtt pop3 pop3s rtsp scp sftp smb smbs smtp smtps telnet tftp
Features: alt-svc AsynchDNS brotli HTTP2 HTTPS-proxy IDN IPv6 Kerberos Largefile libz Metalink MultiSSL NTLM SPNEGO SSL SSPI TLS-SRP zstd
```

I also tried other solutions such as setting http.postBuffer (from https://medium.com/swlh/everything-you-need-to-know-to-resolve-the-git-push-rpc-error-1a865fd1ebea) but they didn't work. I'm pretty confused.. Does anyone have any idea

By the way, I am not an English native speaker. please forgive me if there's any error about grammar.

Comment: Are you able to share with us the repository URL you're trying to clone?

Comment: The `http.postBuffer` option has no effect on clones, and the [Git FAQ outlines why you should not use it without understanding what it does](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitfaq#Documentation/gitfaq.txt-WhatdoescodehttppostBuffercodereallydo).  The problem here is either the remote server or something on your system (e.g., firewall, antivirus, proxy, MITM device) that is intercepting your connection.

Comment: @Iarsks Sorry, but it's a private repository